# Pandas apply function to multiple columns, using value from another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe with some examples, and another dataframe representing a population. For each numeric column in the examples df, I want to calculate the Cumulative Distribution Function of those values with respect to the population df.

This relies on column-wise mean and std values from the population df - and I can't find a way properly refer to these mean and std values in my apply function.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying:

The examples:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([['Azriel', 45, 76], ['Moses', 23, 34]])
df_test.columns = (['Name', 'Age', 'Weight'])
```

```
     Name  Age  Weight
0  Azriel   45      76
1   Moses   23      34
```

The population:

```
df_comp = pd.DataFrame([['Mary', 28, 66], ['Joseph', 32, 86], ['Paul', 54, 88]])
df_comp.columns = (['Name', 'Age', 'Weight'])
```

```
     Name  Age  Weight
0    Mary   28      66
1  Joseph   32      86
2    Paul   54      88
```

I am trying to produce the calculation in df_dist:

```
df_dist = df_test.copy()
numeric_cols = df_comp.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
mu = df_comp[numeric_cols].mean()
sig = df_comp[numeric_cols].std()

df_dist[numeric_cols] = df_dist[numeric_cols].apply(lambda x: scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x, mu, sig))
```

The output of df_dist is:

```
     Name       Age    Weight
0  Azriel  0.691462  0.996679
1   Moses  0.000001  0.000078
```

The expected output of df_dist (calculated manually):

```
                 Age              Weight
Azriel  0.6914624613    0.371154197
Moses   0.1419883859    0.00007804441375
```

You can see, the value for Azriel's Age and Moses's Weight is correct, but the rest are wrong.

I think I am making a mistake trying to referring to mu and sig in the apply function, when I only want to refer to one of the values within mu and sig.

I hope that makes sense - can anyone see a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at `mu` and `sig`, we see they are series and have values for each numeric column:

```
>>> mu

Age       38.0
Weight    80.0
dtype: float64

>>> sigma

Age       14.000000
Weight    12.165525
dtype: float64
```

When you are `apply`ing CDF function per column, you are using the *whole* `mu` and `sigma` series instead of using the corresponding values specific to the column (so your suspicion is correct!).

Remedy is to use the column's name in `apply` and select from the `mu` and `sigma` accordingly:

```py
df_dist[numeric_cols].apply(lambda x: scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x, mu[x.name], sig[x.name]))
```

`x.name` will be e.g. `"Age"` when `Age` column is applied upon, and so on.

This gives:

```
     Name       Age    Weight
0  Azriel  0.691462  0.371154
1   Moses  0.141988  0.000078
```

Comment: Superb - many thanks Mustafa. This solved my problem exactly in seconds.